# Disable scrolling to left/right/up/down in Qwebengineview

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebengineview

I want my qwebengineview can't scroll to the left/right/up/down.
My situation is like this:
[image]
[image: Image2]
It was asked in Qt Fourm first, however I can't find a solution for this.
QT Fourm link: [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93495/how-to-disable-scrolling-past-the-top-bottom-left-right-in-a-qwebengineview-rendered-page)

Please see the minimum code example code below. It's not the same website but can also show this problem.
I'm using Mac Os 10.15 and Qt 5.13.1.

**Update**
mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebEngineView* m_pWebView;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setFixedSize(920,580);

    m_pWebView = new QWebEngineView(this);
    // Set WebView Size
    m_pWebView->setGeometry(0,0,920,580);
    // Disable Right Click
    m_pWebView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    m_pWebView->load(QUrl("https://clash.razord.top/#/proxies"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Sure. please see the update.

Comment: In Linux did not observe the behavior

Comment: I have updated the behavior in my system. I suppose this only happens in mac

Comment: Yes this happens on Mac @Coel did you get some workaround on this ??